# how to draw polygons over shape files in c#.net?

Tags: c#, gis

I have some shape files (shp,shx,dbf) and I want to load them in a division using c#.net, currently I am using easy Gis for web, I want to add the ability for the user to be able to draw a polygon over map so that a closed area is defined , and I want this polygon coordinates so that I can define whether some places are in polygon or not.
Any Idea what is the best plugin or anything for .net , is it possible to be done in Easy GIS?
I would appreciate your help.thanks

P.S:
I should mention that I need this to be done on a webpage, so desktop softwares are useless.

Comment: I think you could do it by using Easy GIS.NET Desktop.Follow this link http://www.easygisdotnet.com/Products.aspx

Comment: Yes but I need to do it on a webpage

Comment: after days of searching ,I found the follwoing link very useful:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example

OpenLayers is a free javascript libray that gives you lots of functionality like drawing polygons and etc ...

Comment: PLease answer your own question and accept it to close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after days of searching ,I found the follwoing link very useful: wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example OpenLayers is a free javascript libray that gives you lots of functionality like drawing polygons and etc ...